# QWebEnginePage abnormal CPU usage

Tags: c++, qt5, cpu-usage, windows-7-x64, qtwebengine

On windows 7 pro x64 with Qt 5.6.1 this line alone is bringing my CPU up to 10-15%:

```
QWebEnginePage *page = new QWebEnginePage(this);
```

Deleting the *page* later (even immediately) does not help in reducing the usage back to 0-1% as usual for my apps. Any ideas what to do?

---

> Full code causing the problem:

**problem.pro**

```
QT       += core gui webenginewidgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = problem
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        MainWindow.cpp

HEADERS  += MainWindow.h

FORMS    += MainWindow.ui
```

**problem.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWebEnginePage>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**problem.cpp**

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Comment the next line to reduce CPU usage back to normal
    QWebEnginePage *page = new QWebEnginePage(this);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With **QNetworkAccessManager** I was able to achieve the same result as with the QWebEnginePage, but without the unnecesarry raised CPU usage.